# sudo: pear: command not found

Tags: php, macos, pear

I have snow leopard which apparently has php with pear pre-installed. I enabled php but could not find any signs of PEAR. So I have installed it and now phpinfo() shows its installation

```
include_path .:/usr/lib/php/share/pear
```

Still when I type in any pear command

```
$ sudo pear
```

I get an error: sudo: pear: command not found

What am I missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)

Comment: How if this question was posted first?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315472/old-question-marked-as-duplicate-of-a-new-question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many ways to skin this cat, but I would type this if you have locate installed (which you probably do):

```
$ locate bin/pear
```

That should list one or more things, one of which will look like the path to pear.  Let's say it says something like `/usr/local/bin/pear`.  Then your next command is:

```
$ sudo /usr/local/bin/pear
```

Two caveats come to mind:

1. It's possible that locate will list multiple executable pear files.  If that's the case, it may be important to pick the right one based on which PHP you're using.
2. You may want to add the directory where `pear` is located to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: locate is not installed... I know the path which is /usr/lib/php/share/pear but the weird thing is that even if i go to that directory i still can't run pear

Comment: That's not the directory where the pear command-line binary is installed.  What happens when you type `locate bin/pear` in a terminal prompt?  Locate is installed by default on every Mac OS X installation I've ever seen, so I'm suprised to see you say it is not installed.  If it truly is not installed, try `whereis pear`.

Comment: If all else fails, you can try `sudo /usr/local/bin/pear` and `sudo /usr/local/php5/bin/pear`.  I've seen pear end up in both locations on Mac OS X.  If you **really** have no idea where it is but are certain it's there somewhere, and you can afford to be very patient you can try something thorough but inefficient like:  `sudo find / -name pear` but that could take a long time to run.  I would be prepared to give it hours at a minimum.  That would be for truly desperate times only, I suspect.  (And it might be a bad idea to run on a production server.)

Comment: so locate says: The locate database (/var/db/locate.database) does not exist.

Comment: whearis pear returns nothing, just goes to the next line

Comment: Oh, OK, so locate is installed, but the database has never been set up.  If you can afford to be patient, you can run `sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb` to set it up.  (I'm assuming you're on a dev machine here and not a production server.)  You'll want to set up a cronjob to keep locate up to date.  (Google it or look on ServerFault.com.)  In the mean time, did you find it in `/usr/local/bin/pear` or `/usr/local/php5/bin/pear` by any chance?

Comment: generating the database for locate . Says it could take some time, no idea how long that is, still not working

Comment: How about this?:  `find /usr -name pear | grep bin/pear`

Comment: pear located: /usr/lib/php/share/pear/PEAR

Comment: You sure that `/usr/lib/php/share/pear/PEAR` isn't a directory rather than the command-line for pear that you're looking for?  Because if that's the executable, you have one crazy pear setup.  :-)

Comment: i lied, i searched for just pear, when i search for bin/pear i get: /usr/lib/php/bin/pear && 
/usr/lib/php/bin/peardev

Comment: Cool!  So now you can either always type `sudo /usr/lib/php/bin/pear` when you want to use it, or you can follow @hayashi-kei's instructions but use this for the line to add:  `export PATH=/usr/lib/php/bin:$PATH`

Comment: sudo pear still doesn't work but at least something works! Thanks Trott!

Comment: haza! got it working, your path was correct, @hayashi-kei had an example path and I blindly copied it. DUH. But export PATH=/usr/lib/php/bin:$PATH works perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

You need to update your system $PATH variable in order for the pear command to work. Edit the bash profile file using the following(if you have textmate):

```
mate ~/.bash_profile
```

and add in this line:

```bash
export PATH=/usr/local/pear/bin:$PATH
```

reload your terminal after that and it should work now

**Edited:**
Thanks for highlighting my mistake trott. I have changed the path to locate where the bin should roughly be(depending on where one chooses to install it)

Comment: So I do have textmate but of course I get mate command not found. I added the path to .bash_profile but it was a new file, so maybe I did it in the wrong spot cause it's still not working

Comment: I'm fairly certain /usr/lib/php/share/pear is not the path of the actually command-line binary, so I do not think this will work.  include_path is the location of PHP files included by things like include() and require().  It would be very surprising and thoroughly facepalm-worthy to find out that the command-line binary is stashed in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed pear directly on `PHP` (`MAMP`, for example) you should copy `pear` to `/usr/local/bin`:

```bash
cp /php5.3.2/pear /usr/local/bin/pear
```

then export var `PATH`, and test with "`pear`" in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and required updating secure_path in sudoers as it overrides user's $PATH.

Check for **secure_path** on sudo

```
[root@host ~]# sudo -V | grep 'Value to override'
Value to override user's $PATH with: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

If `$PATH` is being overriden us `visudo` and edit `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```