# Command not found when using sudo

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have a script called `foo.sh` in my home folder.

When I navigate to this folder, and enter `./foo.sh`, I get

`-bash: ./foo.sh: Permission denied`.

When I use `sudo ./foo.sh`, I get

`sudo: foo.sh: command not found`.

Why does this happen and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

**Permission denied**

In order to run a script the file must have **an executable permission bit set**.

In order to fully understand Linux [file permissions](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/File-permissions.html#File-permissions) you can study the documentation for the `chmod` command. [chmod](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html), an abbreviation of *change mode*, is the command that is used to change the permission settings of a file.

To read the chmod documentation for your local system , run `man chmod` or `info chmod` from the command line. Once read and understood you should be able to understand the output of running ...

```
ls -l foo.sh
```

... which will list the READ, WRITE and EXECUTE permissions for the file owner, the group owner and everyone else who is not the file owner or a member of the group to which the file belongs (that last permission group is sometimes referred to as "world" or "other")

Here's a summary of how to troubleshoot the **Permission Denied error** in your case.

```
$ ls -l foo.sh                    # Check file permissions of foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 rkielty users 0 2012-10-21 14:47 foo.sh 
    ^^^ 
 ^^^ | ^^^   ^^^^^^^ ^^^^^
  |  |  |       |       | 
Owner| World    |       |
     |          |    Name of
   Group        |     Group
             Name of 
              Owner
```

Owner has read and write access rw but the - indicates that the executable permission is missing

The `chmod` command fixes that. (Group and other only have read permission set on the file, they cannot write to it or execute it)

```
$ chmod +x foo.sh               # The owner can set the executable permission on foo.sh
$ ls -l foo.sh                  # Now we see an x after the rw 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 rkielty users 0 2012-10-21 14:47 foo.sh
   ^  ^  ^
```

foo.sh is now executable as far as Linux is concerned.

**Using sudo results in Command not found**

When you run a command using **sudo** you are effectively running it as the superuser or root.

The reason that the root user is not finding your command is likely that the `PATH` environment variable for root does not include the *directory where `foo.sh` is located*. Hence the command is not found.

The PATH environment variable contains a list of directories which are searched for commands. Each user sets their own PATH variable according to their needs. 
To see what it is set to run

```
env | grep ^PATH
```

Here's some sample output of running the above `env` command first as an ordinary user and then as the root user using sudo

```
rkielty@rkielty-laptop:~$ env | grep ^PATH
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

rkielty@rkielty-laptop:~$ sudo env | grep ^PATH
[sudo] password for rkielty: 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
```

Note that, although similar, in this case the directories contained in the PATH the non-privileged user (rkielty) and the super user are *not the same*.

The directory where `foo.sh` resides is not present in the PATH variable of the root user, hence the *command not found* error.

Comment: Weird that `sudo $PWD/temp.sh` doesn't work neither, while `sudo echo $PWD` shows just what I waited for. (Mac)

Comment: @Nakilon if you put that in a question with full details I should be able to troubleshoot it for you further. The issue is likely which shell (your first command shell or the shell launched by sudo) has evaluated $PWD

Comment: @RobKielty, never mind. I don't remember the exact issue, but probably it was smth like not setting chmod -x for one command in script, and calling script via sudo generated not so understandable error msg.

Comment: @Rob: so how does one make `sudo`'s `PATH` the same as the user's?

Comment: @Tom this is a good question, not sure I can answer it in a comment as I would need some context so as to best advise you. But as a starting point I would suggest you review the sudo documentation in full (which is very good) my instinct would be to NOT make the path for root the same as a general user but that instinct is based on running a machine a production environment versus say a private laptop.

Comment: @Rob: I have found a way in the meantime (see my answer below).

Comment: I had this problem with `sudo asterisk -r`, which didn't work. Asterisk is located in `/usr/sbin`, and this was in the root PATH, but not in my user PATH. After adding `/usr/sbin` to my user PATH, it worked. You say "the PATH environment variable for root does not include the directory where foo.sh is located", so you say I should add the path to the root PATH, which is contrary to my findings.

Comment: `sudo`'s `"command not found"` has nothing to do with the PATH; if you set the execute permissions, then `sudo` executes it! It's just some quirk in sudo (that should arguably be fixed; error messages should not be gratuitously inaccurate).

Comment: @Tom you can change the secure_path in /etc/sudoers

Comment: _“The reason that the root user is not finding your command is likely that the `PATH` environment variable for root does not include the directory where `foo.sh` is located.”_ — What? Why do I have to manipulate `PATH`? Why doesn’t `sudo ./foo.sh` get interpreted as `sudo "$(pwd)/foo.sh"`? When running `sudo` in a script, why do I have to write something like `sudo "$(pwd)/$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")"` instead of `sudo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"`?

Comment: Hi @Philip Rego I'm assuming some knowledge of the purpose of sudo. Do u mean with and without sudo?

Comment: I'm wondering why the PATH variable has a different value when I run as sudo compared to my regular user. I set PATH in `/etc/environment` but this PATH is not used when ran as sudo. Where do I set the PATH for use in sudo?

Comment: It should be configured in the shell used by root or possibly via sudo configuration. Review the man pages for each for details. The PATH configured for root is typically limited to a short list of directories so as to prevent user programs from being run by root accidentally and to force the root user to explicitily reference the program name that it is to invoke. This would be seen as good practise from a security point of view. But of course PATH restriction is the tip of the iceberg when it comes to Linux security.

Answer (score 176):

The other solutions I've seen here so far are based on some system definitions, but it's in fact possible to have `sudo` use the current `PATH` (with the `env` command) and/or the rest of the environment (with the `-E` option) just by invoking it right:

```
sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" <command> [arguments]
```

In fact, one can make an alias out of it:

```
alias mysudo='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'
```

(It's also possible to name the alias itself `sudo`, replacing the original `sudo`.)

Comment: I like this solution, Tom, because you are consciously working with a different sudo invocation. It's important to be mindful of what PATH variable is in use at all times whatever way (and there are many) it is set up.

Comment: I believe that this is the correct and most standardized solution for `command not found` issue faced in Ubuntu distro. Thanks man.

Comment: you can add the alias to your `./bashrc` to save it between sessions

Comment: I get "permission denied" after using mysudo.

Comment: You don't explain why they're different in the first place.

Comment: On my system (Xubuntu 22.04.1), you don't have to do anything but make it executable. `sudo ./myscript` just works.

Comment: Good Solution! I wonder why `sudo` doesn't automatically pick up `$PATH`.

Comment: for the alias name, I use `please`, It quite wholesome :)

Answer (score 33):

Check for **secure_path** on sudo

```
[root@host ~]# sudo -V | grep 'Value to override'
Value to override user's $PATH with: /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

If `$PATH` is being overridden use `visudo` and edit `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped to solve a mystery of sudo not being able to run commands.

Comment: You don't explain why they're different in the first place.

Comment: @PhilipRego - These answers are +6 years old, If you don't feel there is enough details on multiple answers... Try offering some suggestions on what you are looking for, or better still edit the answer to provide the details you find lacking.

Comment: sudo -V | grep 'Value to override', comes out empty in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu @Hem. Perhaps the output is different when looking at `sudo -V` and the `grep` isn't capturing the same text. In any case, Review the Manual for Ubunto and Sudoers and see how `secure_path` and other aspects are applied. - https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/sudoers.5.html

Answer (score 8):

1. Check that you have execute permission on the script. i.e. `chmod +x foo.sh`
2. Check that the first line of that script is `#!/bin/sh` or some such.
3. For sudo you are in the wrong directory. check with `sudo pwd`

Answer (score 6):

You can also create a soft link to your script in one of the directories (`/usr/local/bin` for example) in the super user PATH. It'll then be available to the sudo.

```
chmod +x foo.sh
sudo ln -s path-to-foo.sh /usr/local/bin/foo
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/465109/311950) to have an idea of which directory to put soft link in.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that linux will say "command not found" even if you explicitly give the path to the file.

```
[veeam@jsandbox ~]$ sudo /tmp/uid.sh;echo $?
sudo: /tmp/uid.sh: command not found
1
[veeam@jsandbox ~]$ chmod +x /tmp/uid.sh
[veeam@jsandbox ~]$ sudo /tmp/uid.sh;echo $?
0
```

It's a somewhat misleading error, however it's probably technically correct. A file is not a command until its executable, and so cannot be found.

Answer (score 2):

Try `chmod u+x foo.sh` instead of `chmod +x foo.sh` if you have trouble with the guides above. This worked for me when the other solutions did not.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "command not found" when using sudo far less hackier way would be to edit secure_path.

It is perfectly described here:
https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is my solution:
in ~/.bash_aliases just add the following:

```
# ADDS MY PATH WHEN SET AS ROOT
if [ $(id -u) = "0" ]; then
   export PATH=$PATH:/home/your_user/bin 
fi
```

Voila! 
Now you can execute your own scripts with sudo or set as ROOT without having to do an export PATH=$PATH:/home/your_user/bin everytime.

Notice that I need to be explicit when adding my PATH since HOME for superuser is /root

Answer (score -2):

If you are not so comfortable with the command line and are using **Ubuntu** you can solve the problem as follows:

1. Open the folder window where the file is located
2. Right click on the executable file and choose `Properties`
3. Go to the `Permissions` tab and highlight `Allow executing file as program`

[image]

With this solution you allow the user to execute the file as a program and you don't need sudo (or change the `PATH` environment variable for root).

Answer (score -5):

It seems `sudo` command not found

to check whether the sudo package is installed on your system, type `sudo` , and press Enter . If you have `sudo` installed the system will display a short help message, otherwise you will see something like `sudo: command not found`

To install sudo, run one of the following commands using root account:

`apt-get install sudo`  # If your system based on apt package manager

`yum install sudo`      # If your system based on yum package manager

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since the issue was the set executable bit not being set on the script.

Comment: It's not the sudo command that wasn't found. The output means that is sudo "saying" that the "foo.sh" command wasn't found.