# Certbot not found

Tags: ssl, ubuntu-16.04, lets-encrypt, certbot

i installed letsencrypt on my ubuntu 16.04 machine with following command.

```
sudo apt-get install letsencrypt
```

Now, i want to define a cronjob to automatically renew my certs with following line.

```
certbot renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"
```

But i always get the error, that the command certbot could not be found.

If i use letsencrypt instead of certbot everything works fine as long as i dont use the `--pre-hook` and `--post-hook`.

How to install `certbot`or is there an alternative command for letsencrypt to define such hooks?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i found the solution..

`git clone git@github.com:certbot/certbot.git`

`cd certbot`

`./certbot-auto renew --pre-hook "service nginx stop" --post-hook "service nginx start"`

Comment: It is good practice to install certbot via python package manager `pip`: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/certbot/0.17.0.
Latest Ubuntu 17.04 (Zesty) has certbot in it's repository as well.

Comment: root@f114791e9f83:/certbot# ./certbot-auto
bash: ./certbot-auto: No such file or directory

Answer (score 20):

For me the following commands working fine.

**Install snap**

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install snapd
```

**Install Core**

```
sudo snap install core
```

**Install Certbot**

```
sudo snap install --classic certbot

sudo ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
```

**Renew Certbot**

```
sudo certbot renew --dry-run
```

Comment: Ran those and got: "certbot: command not found"

Comment: I got >>snap "certbot" is not available<<

Answer (score 7):

Follow the [official instructions](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions) and install `certbot` with

```bash
sudo snap install --classic certbot
```

or, in older Ubuntus that don't have `snap`, with

```bash
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

It will be available in `$PATH` after that.

Comment: Oh man, this is the perfect answer. Follow official instructions. I didn't and suffered.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. I have to specify full path when running certbot with elevated privileges

```
sudo /snap/bin/certbot renew --dry-run
```

TL;DR

Although I have **/snap/bin** in my $PATH

```
echo $PATH
```

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:/snap/bin

But without providing full path it does not work with **sudo**. It throws the following error

```
certbot renew --dry-run
```

> ```
> The following error was encountered:
> [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/log/letsencrypt/.certbot.lock'
> Either run as root, or set --config-dir, --work-dir, and --logs-dir to writeable paths.
> ```

and it also works if I (while having /snap/bin in root's $PATH as well) switch to power user

```
sudo -i
```

and then run any certbot command

Kindly note I'm on debian 10 and using **snapd** as package manager *according to the tutorial https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/snap-nginx*.

As explained here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245772/why-running-command-as-sudo-returns-command-not-found this is kinda expected and approved of behaviour:

> sudo tries to be safe when executing external commands. the usual
> workaround is to specify the complete pathname of the program. It's
> also more secure; it you don't specify the path, it's conceivable that
> an attacker could create another program that will be run with root
> permissions.

Going on reading further I can see that my PATHs are different

```
env | grep ^PATH
sudo env | grep ^PATH
```

There are several solutions (use custom sudo or change sudo $PATH) provided at the thread [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo) so one does not have to specify full path.

Answer (score 1):

try to remove using snap
`sudo snap remove certbot`

and then install again with
`sudo snap install --classic certbot`

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Let's Certbot](https://github.com/jinhucheung/letscertbot).

Let's Certbot is a tool builds automated scripts base on Certbot for obtaining, renewing, deploying SSL certificates.

It supports docker and non-docker environments.

GitHub: https://github.com/jinhucheung/letscertbot

Answer (score 0):

try this
sudo ~/.certbot/bin/certbot certonly --webroot