# How do I execute a Unix shell script?

Tags: shell, unix

I am working in the latest version of Ubuntu and am very new to coding and StackOverflow.

I created a simple script to echo "Hello World".

The script's name is `helloworld.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Hello World"
```

I try to run it using `sudo ./helloworld.sh`, but receive the following prompt:

```
sudo: ./helloworld.sh: command not found
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `chmod +x helloworld.sh`

You can determine the specific file permissions by running `ls -l`, which will now show that you have executable permission for the file `helloworld.sh`, allowing you to run it with `./`.

If you do not have permission to change mode (`chmod`), try running your script as `sh helloworld.sh`.

Lastly, you shouldn't need to be running with `sudo` unless there are some strict permissions set on the account.

Comment: That last point should be emphasized: there's no reason to use `sudo`, and you should never use `sudo` (or otherwise do anything with `root` permissions) unless there's a valid reason to do so.