# Sudo doesn't recognize specific commands

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, jhipster, sudo

I'm currently a student and I must installed Jhipster for a project, the installation seems to work fine but I faced many problems. Indeed, when I want to compile jdl files, I want to do it with a sudo but jhipster is not find only when I used sudo (without it it works)

[image: with sudo]

Furthermore when I tried to launch a Jhipster project I must do ./mnvw or sudo ./mnvw. Here again when I use sudo, a warning spawn with the following message : "Warning: JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set.". This warning is not here when I don't put sudo.

So I would like to know why theses commands doesn't work with sudo, I don't have any troubles with other commands. Thanks in advances for your help, sorry for my english level and all the mistakes I made.

Comment: `jhipster` may be an alias or shell function, rather than an executable file. `sudo` also ignores your environment for security reasons.

Comment: Yes, I found that sudo doesn't access cause of the path, I created an alias "sudo2" with the following command : "alias sudo2='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'"

Problem solved

Comment: @pjh You're right, my bad !

I will edit my answer to include the link !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved my problem, I don't know if the way I did it is "clean" but I created an alias in my bashrc with the following text :

**alias sudo2='sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH"'**

Now I use sudo2 to launch Jhipster or mnvw

***I know it's not good to answer to ourself but it's for helping if someone face the same problem in the future ;)***

Another similar subject with high voted answers : [Command not found when using sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12996397/command-not-found-when-using-sudo)